# Android dagger2 inject intent into viewModel using Factory

Tags: java, android, dagger-2, android-architecture-components, android-viewmodel

As an example i am using Google sample - [GithubBrowserSample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/tree/master/GithubBrowserSample) (i use java version, it can be found [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/tree/b1a194c1ae267258cd002e2e1c102df7180be473/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github))

What want to achieve:

1. Start activity with intent extra
2. Inject extra into viewModel constructor

My activity(in witch i want pass intent) module:

```java
@Module
public abstract class AddEditTaskModule {

    @Provides
    @Nullable
    static String provideTaskId(AddEditTaskActivity activity) {
        return activity.getIntent().getStringExtra(AddEditTaskActivity.EDIT_TASK_ID);
    }

    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    abstract AddEditTaskFragment contributeAddEditTaskFragment();

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelScope(AddEditTaskViewModel.class)
    abstract ViewModel bindAddEditTaskViewModel(AddEditTaskViewModel viewModel);
}
```

my factory:

```java
public class ViewModelFactory implements ViewModelProvider.Factory {

    private final Map<Class<? extends ViewModel>, Provider<ViewModel>> creators;

    @Inject
    public ViewModelFactory(Map<Class<? extends ViewModel>, Provider<ViewModel>> creators) {
        Timber.d("@Inject constructor");
        this.creators = creators;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public <T extends ViewModel> T create(@NonNull Class<T> modelClass) {
        Provider<? extends ViewModel> creator = creators.get(modelClass);
        if (creator == null) {
            for (Map.Entry<Class<? extends ViewModel>, Provider<ViewModel>> entry : creators.entrySet()) {
                if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(entry.getKey())) {
                    creator = entry.getValue();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (creator == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("unknown model class " + modelClass);
        }
        try {
            return (T) creator.get();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Timber.e(e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

in Google's example - factory annotated as `@Singleton`

In my case - i can't use it as a singleton, because i need to bind viewModel in activity module - to pass intentExtra from there.

SO, it's working, but every time i try to getting viewModel by

```java
@Inject
ViewModelProvider.Factory viewModelFactory;
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
    AddEditTaskViewModel mViewModel =
        ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory).get(AddEditTaskViewModel.class);
}
```

new Factory is created.

This seems very wrong to me.
What am i doing wrong?

**Edit:**

**Solution #1:**

Create custom factory for this kind of ViewModels

```java
public class AddEditTaskViewModel extends ViewModel {

    ...

    public static class Factory extends ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory{
        @NonNull
        private final Application application;
        @Nullable
        private final String taskId;

        @Inject
        public Factory(@NonNull Application application, @Nullable String taskId){
            Timber.d("Constructor");
            this.application = application;
            this.taskId = taskId;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public <T extends ViewModel> T create(@NonNull Class<T> modelClass) {
            //noinspection unchecked
            return (T) new AddEditTaskViewModel(application, taskId);
        }
    }
}
```

ActivtyModule:

```java
@Module
public abstract class AddEditTaskModule {
    @Provides
    @Nullable
    static String provideTaskId(AddEditTaskActivity activity) {
        return activity.getIntent().getStringExtra(AddEditTaskActivity.EDIT_TASK_ID);
    }

    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    abstract AddEditTaskFragment contributeAddEditTaskFragment();

    @Provides
    static AddEditTaskViewModel.Factory bindAddEditTaskViewModelFactory(Application application, @Nullable String id){
        return new AddEditTaskViewModel.Factory(application, id);
    }
}
```

now, use in in our activity and fragments in this activity:

```java
@Inject
AddEditTaskViewModel.Factory viewModelFactory;

AddEditTaskViewModel mViewModel =
                ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory).get(AddEditTaskViewModel.class);
```

This also works. The problem is, that in this case i need to copy ViewModel's constructor 3(!!) times: 1. in dagger module, 2. in factory, 3. in viewModel.

And i can't just use:

```java
@Binds
abstract AddEditTaskViewModel.Factory bindAddEditTaskViewModelFactory(AddEditTaskViewModel.Factory factory);
```

because - circular dependency

This solution seems bad for me to.

**Solution #2:**

Use two ViewModelFactory.

First one global, annotated with `@Singleton`. Witch will be used for ViewModels without cases like "inject intent extra into ViewModel".

Second one - cope of ViewModelFactory, but without `@Singleton` annotation. Should be used in activity module with `@Named` tag like this:

```java
@Binds
@Named(AddEditTaskViewModel.TAG)
abstract ViewModelProvider.Factory bindAddEditTaskViewModelFactory(ViewModelFactoryTarget factory);
```

in activity/fragment:

```java
@Inject
@Named(AddEditTaskViewModel.TAG)
ViewModelProvider.Factory viewModelFactory;
```

Okay, this seems better solution that any of above, except several "but":

1. I have two identical classes of ViewModelFactory, witch are different only by `@Singleton` annotation.
2. Using `@Named` is not very elegant as for me.

Answer (score 1):

Tuned out, it is more simpler than i thought.

**For common ViewModels:**

remove `@Singleton` annotation from ViewModelFactory.

Add `@Singleton` to *ViewModelModule*

```java
@Binds
@Singleton
abstract ViewModelProvider.Factory bindViewModelFactory(ViewModelFactory factory);
```

For ViewModels, where we need usage of Intent Extra injections:

ActivityModule:

```java
@Provides
@Nullable
static String provideTaskId(AddEditTaskActivity activity) {
    return activity.getIntent().getStringExtra(AddEditTaskActivity.EDIT_TASK_ID);
}

@Binds
@Named(AddEditTaskViewModel.TAG)
abstract ViewModelProvider.Factory bindAddEditTaskViewModelFactory(ViewModelFactory factory);
```

Than use in activity/fragment:

```java
@Inject
@Named(AddEditTaskViewModel.TAG)
ViewModelProvider.Factory viewModelFactory;
```